# google cloud vs aws service roles

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, amazon-iam, google-cloud-iam

Im coming from AWS not sure how to do this with gcp.

In AWS I can create an EC2 instance, Lambda, ECS, etc service role. I attach policies to that role to give it the access it needs. Then I attach the role to an EC2 instance, lambda, etc. No static keys being used, no secrets being passed around.

How do I do this with gcp? How do I attach a role (or maybe gcp service account?) to a gce instance, cloud function, gke deployment/service, etc?

GCP has "service accounts" and something it calls roles and something called "scopes" but it is not clear to me how to attach them and Grant access to reasources implicitly (without passing around secrets/keys).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For services such as Compute Engine, App Engine, etc. Google automatically creates a [default service account](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts#compute_engine_service_account). When you create an instance or when the instance is shutdown you can modify the privileges assigned to default service account or even change the service account used.

The default service account has a predefined name `[PROJECT_NUMBER]-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com`

This [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts#compute_engine_default_service_account) will provide more information.

You can access the credentials created by the default service account from the instance [metadata](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata). Here is an example in Python. This example load the default service account credentials for accessing Google Cloud Storage:

```
from google.auth import compute_engine
from google.cloud import storage
credentials = compute_engine.Credentials()
client = storage.Client(credentials=credentials, project=project)
```

A common strategy is to use Application Default Credentials (ADC) to automatically locate credentials:

```
from google.cloud import storage
client = storage.Client()
```

Comment: How does this work with gke? Can I assign a role to the cluster? More importantly, can I assign a role to a gke deployment or service?

Comment: Create a new question for Kubernetes

Comment: This link will help you get started with Kubernetes, credentials, etc. https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/authenticating-to-cloud-platform

Comment: So I could create my own service account and attach it to instances too right? I wouldn't want to use the default account for all instances

Comment: Yes, you can create a new service account and assign it to a specific VM instance.

Answer (score 1):

For a VM you will need to stop it first. You can follow the below steps:

1. Create a service account with necessary privileges by going to https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts?project={project-id}
2. Go to VMs list.
3. Stop the VM
4. Click no the VM name. Click edit at the top.
5. Scroll down to the service account section.
6. Pick the service account that you want to associate to the VM.

Comment: And after doing this any gcp API calls made on the instance will automatically run with the service accounts creds right?